# When using jquery modal, how do I halt processing until a button has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

This might seem like a silly question because as I understand it, the modal command should halt processing, but with my code it's not doing so.

Here's the code in question:

```
const selectPiece = () => {
    $('#pick').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    }); 
};
```

And the html it's acting on:

```
<div id="pick" class="modal fade row" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Promote pawn to...?</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger promote" id='btn-rook'
                                        data-dismiss="modal">Rook</button>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger promote" id='btn-knight'
                                        data-dismiss="modal">Knight</button>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger promote" id='btn-bishop'
                                        data-dismiss="modal">Bishop</button>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger promote" id='btn-queen'
                                        data-dismiss="modal">Queen</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap here.

The popup has 4 buttons. I need processing to stop until 1 has been pressed.

Comment: What process do you want to stop?

Comment: Yes, what do you mean with processing? A modal is just an html overlay and doesnt stop any script execution like alert() would do.

Comment: It's a chess program. When the player has made his move, the computer automatically does the same. When this modal pops up, I need the computer to wait before doing so.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I'm running this with node.

Comment: I've just realised that I'm using the bootstrap modal command which doesn't halt processing.